# Display highchart tooltip using Jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, highcharts, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to display values of multiple text areas as tooltip for various points in a highchart graph.On button click a dialog box will open containing text areas.on clicking OK button these inputs will be displayed as tooltip of various points of a highchart line graph..I am able to take input from text areas but when I am trying to put them inside a custom dialog box then the jquery ui custom dialog box is not getting displayed along with the highcharts graph..

I have used this code for tooltip..

Dialog box code..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 350,
        height: 500,
        modal : true,
        resizable: false,
        show:"slow"
    });

    $('#button').click(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        $("#myDialogText").text("Data");
    });
});
```

Here is the js fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/13/

I have used input selector to take values from text area.Do i need to add specific selectors for custom dialog box as well or the existing ones will work??

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was in the way you included js libraries, you had several jqueryui libaries, and had error in console

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts'
```

Does [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/16/) work properly for you ?

Comment: yes this works only thing that the tooltips should be unique for every month ie even if 2 or more point of a series have same value their tool tip should be different but I am getting them same as seen in this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/20/..I am not being able to rectify the logic behind this..

Comment: then you just need to put `<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>` out of dialog div see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/19/)